Check if a string contains all words in a phrase from a list in python
I have a list of phrases and I need to be able to identify whether each row in a dataset contains all the words from any of the phrases in my list. Take my example problem below.
I have a dataset where the column "Search" contains some browser searches. I also have a list called "phrases" that contains the phrases I'm trying to find within the Search column.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = [('how to screenshot on mac', 0),
         ('how to take screenshot?', 0),
         ('how to take screenshot on windows', 0),
         ('when is christmas', 0),
         ('how many days until christmas', 0),
        ('how many weeks until christmas', 0),
        ('how much is the new google pixel 8', 0),
        ('which google pixel versions are available', 0),
        ('how do I do google search on my pixel phone 7a', 0)]
labels = ['Search','Random_Column']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(text, columns=labels)

phrases = ['mac screenshot', 'days until christmas', 'google pixel 7a']

I don't care about the order of the words within "phrases" and there can be other before before, within, and after the phrase, but I need to make sure that only the df rows that contain all the words within any of the phrases are identified. Therefore, the expected output would be like this:
                                           Search  Random_Column  Match
0                        how to screenshot on mac              0   True
1                         how to take screenshot?              0  False
2               how to take screenshot on windows              0  False
3                               when is christmas              0  False
4                   how many days until christmas              0   True
5                  how many weeks until christmas              0  False
6              how much is the new google pixel 8              0  False
7       which google pixel versions are available              0  False
8  how do I do google search on my pixel phone 7a              0   True

I have found a lot of solutions for instances where the "phrases" list is made up of single words (e.g. here, here, and here) but I'm struggling to find a solution where I need to match full phrases.
I also tried to implement this solution but could not get it to work for a dataset.

You have to loop over all phrase until you find a match. An efficient option would be to use sets (set.issubset) combined with any:
# convert the phrases to set
sets = [set(s.split()) for s in phrases]
# [{'screenshot', 'mac'}, {'until', 'christmas', 'days'},
#  {'google', 'pixel', '7a'}]

# for each string, check if one of the sets is a subset
# if a match is found, return True immediately
df['Match'] = [any(S.issubset(lst) for S in sets)
               for lst in map(str.split, df['Search'])]

Output:
                                           Search  Random_Column  Match
0                        how to screenshot on mac              0   True
1                         how to take screenshot?              0  False
2               how to take screenshot on windows              0  False
3                               when is christmas              0  False
4                   how many days until christmas              0   True
5                  how many weeks until christmas              0  False
6              how much is the new google pixel 8              0  False
7       which google pixel versions are available              0  False
8  how do I do google search on my pixel phone 7a              0   True


This is short and simple.

@mozway This worked perfectly on my actual dataset, thank you !!

You can use set() and define a _match function:
def _match(x, sets):
    s = set(x.lower().split())
    for ps in sets:
        if ps.issubset(s):
            return True
    return False


Pre-compute the sets initially, for efficiency (see @mozway comments below)
sets = [set(phrase.lower().split()) for phrase in phrases]


Then, apply() the _match method, as a lambda:
df['Match'] = df['Search'].apply(lambda x: _match(x, sets))


Code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def _match(x, sets):
    s = set(x.lower().split())
    for ps in sets:
        if ps.issubset(s):
            return True
    return False

text = [('how to screenshot on mac', 0),
        ('how to take screenshot?', 0),
        ('how to take screenshot on windows', 0),
        ('when is christmas', 0),
        ('how many days until christmas', 0),
        ('how many weeks until christmas', 0),
        ('how much is the new google pixel 8', 0),
        ('which google pixel versions are available', 0),
        ('how do I do google search on my pixel phone 7a', 0)]
labels = ['Search', 'Random_Column']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(text, columns=labels)

phrases = ['mac screenshot', 'days until christmas', 'google pixel 7a']
sets = [set(phrase.lower().split()) for phrase in phrases]
df['Match'] = df['Search'].apply(lambda x: _match(x, sets))

print(df)


Prints
                                           Search  Random_Column  Match
0                        how to screenshot on mac              0   True
1                         how to take screenshot?              0  False
2               how to take screenshot on windows              0  False
3                               when is christmas              0  False
4                   how many days until christmas              0   True
5                  how many weeks until christmas              0  False
6              how much is the new google pixel 8              0  False
7       which google pixel versions are available              0  False
8  how do I do google search on my pixel phone 7a              0   True


Note
If you wanted to make any changes, you can simply modify _match(). It is easy to maintain.

The drawback of using a function (here), is that this recomputes the split/set for each string, which is inefficient. A better approach would be to use a function factory or a class.

No, here you recompute set(phrase.lower().split()) for each row. So in terms of this part of the computation, the complexity is O(N*M) time vs O(M) if you pre-compute the sets. The actual computation is otherwise O(N*M) (N being the number of rows and M the number of phrases).

I tested both approaches for ~10k rows and 300 phrases, precomputing (like in my approach) runs in 3.5s, recomputing the sets in the function runs in 6s.

@mozway My bad! Updated. Thanks. You're absolutely right.
